# Best way to access files inside of directories with common part of dirname

Tags: bash, scripting, regular-expression, directory, filenames

the title is not self-explanatory at all, but I don't know how to formulate it correctly. I will explain with an example.

I have a directory structure like this:

- results/

  ```
     test_0_part1_x000/
     test_0_part2_x010/
     test_0_part3_x122/
     test_1_part1_x121/
     test_1_part2_x009/ 
          ....
  ```

and so on. Basically there's a result/ directory which has ~500 directories. these dirs are "grouped" by test, so all the test_0_part* dir refers to the same test bench(let's say there are like 50 tests, so I have test_0_* to test_49_* directories).

In every directory there's one file that I need to collect and group in a single directory called, in case of test_0, test_0/ and has to contain all the files in the test_0_part* directories.

Actually, my approach is to iterate through all the directories in result/ and by comparing directories' names, collecting the files in the correct end directory. It is working, but it seems not smart at all, given that I could use regex or something similar to handle the problem. Unfortunately, my bash scripting and in general my bash understanding is still very basic and I don't know what to look at in order to improve the code. I would like to take advantage of regular expressions to perform a more clean selection and copy of files, that would be safer than just iterate through all of them sequentially.

My code looks like this:

```
    #! /bin/bash
    OUTDIR=""  #output dir - where to place the files from same test
    INFILES=""  #collection of input files for each test

    last_dir="" 
    #iterate through all the directories in result/
    for d in */; do

    subdirname=${d%???????????} #getting only the first part of dir name (i.e. test0, test1, etc)

    #if new directory is different from the last one, then it is related to a new test. move alle the files collected so far to the OUTDIR directory and clean the OUTDIR content
    if [[ "$last_dir" != "$subdirname" &&  ! -z "$last_dir" ]]; then                
            echo "copying for $last_dir test:"
            echo "$INFILES" | tr " " "\n"
            echo "output directory: $OUTDIR"
            mkdir ${OUTDIR}
            mv ${INFILES} ${OUTDIR}/
            OUTDIR=""
    fi
    
    #if output dir is empty, then get the name from the current dir and clean the input files list 
    if [ -z "$OUTDIR" ]; then
            OUTDIR=${subdirname}
            INFILES=""
    fi
    
    # collect file(s) in the current directory and append to the list
    for fname in ${d}*;
    do
            INFILES="${INFILES} ${fname}"
    done

    last_dir=${subdirname}

    done
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SE! There isn't really a question here, only the description of a problem. Please provide a minimal example by editing your question ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) and also include what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`, to move all the `test_n_part*/*` files into `test_n`:

```
autoload zmv
mkmv() {mkdir -p -- $2:h && mv -- "$@"}

zmv -n -P mkmv '(test_<->)_part*/(*)' '$1/$2'
```

(remove the `-n` for dry-run if happy).

Add `(#qD)` to the source pattern to also move hidden files.